# Using LIKE in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I want to update the location ID for an existing department, which has location ID preceded with 'HQ' as 'HQ-BLR-101'.

Table name : Department

```
Column name       Data type    Constraints

DEPARTMENT_ID     NUMBER(5)     PK

DEPARTMENT_NAME   VARCHAR2(25)  NOT NULL

LOCATION_ID       VARCHAR2(15)

Sample Output:
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME    LOCATION_ID

---------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------

                xxxx            xxxxx                                   HQ-BLR-101
```

I have written this code -

```
declare
v_loc department.location_id%type;
begin
select 'HQ-BLR-101' into v_loc from department where location_id like 'HQ%';
insert into department(department_id, department_name, location_id) 
select department_id, department_name, v_loc from department where location_id like 'HQ%';
commit;
end;
/
```

Can you please help me find the error in this code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you'd edit your question and tell us what errors you're getting, but one thing jumps out: if there is more than one row in DEPARTMENT with LOCATION_ID LIKE 'HQ%' your first statement is going to fail with a "TOO MANY ROWS" error. Fortunately, I don't think you need that statement. I suggest you try:

```
begin
  insert into department
    (department_id, department_name, location_id) 
  select department_id, department_name, 'HQ-BLR-101'
    from department
    where location_id like 'HQ%';

  commit;
end;
```

But in the first sentence of your question you say you want to **update** the existing location. To do that you should use:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT
  SET LOCATION_ID = 'HQ-BLR-101'
  WHERE LOCATION_ID LIKE 'HQ%';
```

Comment: Yeah! Just the update function works fine for this question. Thanks a lot again:)